# Alfresco 4 webservice implementation with C#

Tags: c#, xml, open-source, alfresco

I need to create a website in C# and need to use alfresco web service for process. In my site I need to create all the process that alfresco does through web service. I have seen the web services links in alfresco site. Its not documented as expected. I googled and found this one  http://forge.alfresco.com/gf/project/dotnet/frs/

But this open source is in VB.NET. I need the same in C#. Can you please help me out?

Regards
Dipen

Comment: What bit are you having trouble with - creating a webservice in C#, or working with the Alfresco provided webservices?

Comment: @Gagravarr - Buddy, i'm new to C# and alfresco too. So if any implementation is available means that would help me to understand the concept. Here i know the overall concept. I can able to add web service. but i dont know how to utilize those. please help me with some code

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to learn too much in one go... Why not start by using Alfresco Web Services from a language you do know, then when you've got the hang of that switch them over to C#?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to consider other APIs before starting the developement of your application.

The Alfresco Web Services API is based on the SOAP protocol and it was the first API exposed by Alfresco. It was mainly created to work on Enterprise Services Bus (ESB) contexts and it could be useful only if you need to execute a vector of operations against the repository exchanging messages.

This API is based on a different model/schema called Content Manipulation Language (CML) that was created by Alfresco for managing remote calls. Personally I think that this is not easy to understand because it is quite different from the core model of Alfresco.

So I suggest to avoid the use of the Alfresco Web Services API.

Now the best approach that I suggest is to use CMIS (REST binding) or Spring WebScripts.

CMIS is a new standard supported by many ECM systems now and it stands for Content Management Interoperability Services. It contains some CRUDs methods to manipulate contents in the repository.

You could have some issues using CMIS only if you are using some specific Alfresco features that are not mapped in the CMIS specification.

The good point is that your client application based on CMIS can talk with any CMIS-compliant repository (Alfresco, OpenText, SharePoint, FileNet, Hippo, etc...)

Another good approach is to use the Alfresco REST API (WebScripts) that you can extend for your needs to expose REST methods that can be configured atomically.

This means that you can expose an HTTP method from Alfresco with your custom URL that can execute many operations in the repo but atomically. This means that if some errors are returned, the framework will rollback for you :)

Comment: OP said he "needs" to use it, so I'm not sure how useful it is to tell him he should use something else.